# setup global gradle build dir relative path

Tags: android, variables, gradle, ramdisk

I would like to setup a global gradle build dir that points to a ramdisk. 
I've tried numerous ways of setting up the build dir in my global `gradle.properties` file located at `~/.gradle/gradle.properties`.

The issue I'm facing is that gradle does not evaluate the variables/relative-expressions that are included in the `buildDir` config. 
How do I setup a global build dir that takes care of project specific subfolders?

```
gradle.projectsLoaded {
    rootProject.allprojects {
        buildDir=~/.gradle/build/${rootProject.name}/${project.name}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I've figured it out. The main reason for my issues where that I've assumed that the `gradle.properties` files also executes included scripting expressions (i.e., the included variables and string formatting).

This is not the case!

So, to solve this issue I came up with the following `init.gradle` file (`~/.gradle/init.gradle`):

```
allprojects {
        buildDir="$System.env.HOME/.gradle/build/${it.name}/"
}
```